# System.isScheduled() not working in Scheduler/Batch

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, asynchronous

I have a Scheduler class which executes a batch class. I also execute this batch class from a VF page. 
Deep down in the class hierarchy, I want to check if this batch was called from a Scheduler or a VF page.

I tried using the `isScheduled()` method but this always returns false. Why is that?

My workaround, for now, is setting a boolean depending on where it's called from.

Here's my scheduler code:

```
global with sharing class Demo_Scheduler implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '===== ' + System.isScheduled()); //this returns false
        Database.executeBatch(
            new Demo_Batch(true, new List<SObject>()),
            1
        );
    }

}
```

This is how I'm running it (could be the issue?) I know this is not how you schedule it ideally.

```
Demo_Scheduler sched = new Demo_Scheduler();
sched.execute(null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.isScheduled (and the other flags like this), only apply to the current transaction. In other words, when the scheduler kicks off the batch, the batch itself isn't in the scheduler context, and so System.isScheduled returns false. Setting a flag within the class itself would be appropriate; it's not a workaround that should be avoided.

---

Edit Based on Edit:

Running a scheduled class "manually" does not count as being in a scheduled context. You must use System.scheduleJob:

```
System.scheduleJob('JobName','0 0 0 * * ?', new Demo_Scheduler());
```

System.isScheduled will only return true for a job ran through this interface.

Comment: System.isScheduled() within the scheduler doesn't return true either. In what case will the isScheduled() return true?

Comment: @d_k it should return true while in a scheduled context. Perhaps you could write a specific example that demonstrates your problem, we could help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question please review.

Comment: @d_k That isn't a scheduled context. Edited my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule the job, instead of calling the execute method directly.

```
Demo_Scheduler m = new Demo_Scheduler ();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?'; // cron expression
String jobID = system.schedule('Job name', sch, m);
```

You can find more information about building cron expression and `system.schedule()` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm#d14160e296-d14272e129)